# How to get most recent row by each week for each ID? Week startsThursday and ends Wednesday

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

School updates the records for different subjects every day. They're only supposed to update once a week, however, they update multiple times within a week and some schools don't update. I would like to get most recent data for each week, if school hasn't reported data for current week, it should get most recent record from previous week as this week.

Week Starts from Thursday and ends on Wednesday. Only 1 most recent record needed for each week.

| SchoolID | Math | Science | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5001 | 500 | 400 | 12/02/20 |
| 5001 | 504 | 405 | 12/03/20 |
| 5001 | 555 | 352 | 12/04/20 |
| 5001 | 458 | 452 | 12/05/20 |
| 5001 | 450 | 555 | 12/06/20 |
| 5001 | 504 | 405 | 12/08/20 |
| 5001 | 504 | 405 | 12/14/20 |
| 4551 | 80 | 85 | 12/01/20 |
| 4551 | 80 | 85 | 12/02/20 |
| 4551 | 100 | 105 | 12/14/20 |
| 4551 | 101 | 106 | 12/15/20 |

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
SELECT SchoolID, Math, Science, Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Srn
FROM SchoolTable
GROUP BY SchoolID, Math, Science
ORDER BY SchoolID
    ) AS x
WHERE x.srn = 1
```

Above code will give only most recent data but how can I modify so it will give result for each week? If some school didn't reported record, how do I use most recent record from previous week? 4451 didn't updated record for 12/09/2020 but it's getting previously updated record.

Result should be following.

| SchoolID | Math | Science | Date | Period Reported |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5001 | 500 | 400 | 12/2/2020 | 12/2/2020 |
| 5001 | 504 | 405 | 12/8/2020 | 12/9/2020 |
| 5001 | 504 | 405 | 12/14/2020 | 12/16/2020 |
| 4551 | 80 | 85 | 12/2/2020 | 12/2/2020 |
| 4551 | 80 | 85 | 12/2/2020 | 12/9/2020 |
| 4551 | 101 | 106 | 12/15/2020 | 12/16/2020 |

Comment: It's not clear from your picture what result you want. Is the row in yellow highlighted because it's the only row you actually want in the output, or something else? Can you post the sample data and results you want using text instead of pictures? Especially since you call out 4451 in text but it's 4551 in the picture.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have removed the highlight. Result should be as above. Most recent row should be return for week, if they didn't reported data for given week, it should get most recent record from previous week.

Comment: What if they didn't report data for three weeks?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It should return previously updated record (four week prior) for all three weeks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am sorry, I didn't know how to upload data so, I used as an image.

Comment: That's problematic in a relational query. Can't the front end drag that date across all those empty rows?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by week, but you can use `datepart()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT SchoolID, Math, Science, Date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID, YEAR(date), DATEPART(week, Date) ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Srn
      FROM SchoolTable
      GROUP BY SchoolID, Math, Science
     ) x
WHERE x.srn = 1;
```

This uses the built-in definition of week in SQL Server.

Comment: This will not work as DATEPART(week, Date) will consider Sunday to Saturday as week.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be simpler, but here is one way.

```
SET DATEFIRST 4; -- set Thursday as start of week

;WITH SchoolData AS
(
  SELECT 
    SchoolID, Math, Science, [Date],
    we = DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ([Date])), [Date]),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID, DATEPART(WEEK, ([Date])) ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM dbo.SchoolTable -- WHERE -- filter here to not get all of time
),
AllSchools AS (SELECT SchoolID FROM SchoolData GROUP BY SchoolID),
WeekRange  AS (SELECT MinWe = MIN(we), MaxWe = MAX(we) FROM SchoolData),
Weeks AS
(
  SELECT We = MinWe, MaxWe FROM WeekRange
  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, We), MaxWe 
    FROM Weeks WHERE We < MaxWe
),
final AS
(
  SELECT s.SchoolID, d.Math, d.Science, d.[Date], w.We
  FROM AllSchools AS s 
  CROSS APPLY Weeks AS w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SchoolData AS d
  ON s.SchoolID = d.SchoolID AND w.We = d.we AND d.rn = 1
)
SELECT SchoolID, 
  Math    = COALESCE(Math,    LAG(Math,    1) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We)),
  Science = COALESCE(Science, LAG(Science, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We)),
  [Date]  = COALESCE([Date],  LAG([Date],  1) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We)),
  [Period Reported] = We
FROM final
ORDER BY SchoolID DESC, [Period Reported];
```

If you need to support more trailing weeks, I highly recommend letting the client side do that, but you can add more `LAG`s to each `COALESCE`, e.g.

```
 Math = COALESCE(Math,    LAG(Math,    1) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We),
                          LAG(Math,    2) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We),
                          LAG(Math,    3) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY We)),
```